# How can I retrieve my deactive plugin on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a site on wordPress, which has a problem. The problem was that I can't login to my account. The message :
There has been a critical error in your site.

I search via google and I assumed that one  update of a plugin, creates this error. So I found a solution,
to remame the plugins folder as plugins.hold and then rename again to plugin.

Yes , I managed to connect to my site, but now I  don't have my plugins.

What could I do to correct it ???

Comment: Change the folder name back and reactivate your plugins...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is seems to be more suited to [wordpress.se].

Comment: @KenY-N What would be in-scope for SO and WordPress then? All questions with the tag "wordpress" should be on SE:WP then.

Comment: If you checked the Wordpress tag when you were selecting it for the question, or if you hover over it now, you will see what is in scope for WP here:  "This tag is for programming-specific questions about the WordPress content management system. Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc. These are best asked on the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com)". This is not a coding-related question so it is not suitable for SO.